# Trying to learn bug-bounties, how do I use the practice sites like hackthissite and hacmebank?

Tags: professional-education, bug-bounty

Do I just attack those sites while they're live, or is there a way to download the site to attack offline?  The reason I'm curious is because if those sites are vulnerable and being used for practice all the time, wouldn't multiple hackers interfere with one another?

What I've seen in the various learning resources I've been to is just, "go practice on these sites", but no explanation as to the process by which you do that.

Comment: Did you actually go to the homepage of https://www.hackthissite.org/ ? It's saying right there what you're supposed to do: read the guide and create an account.

Comment: Okay, I do see that now, thank you.  I was more using them as examples, as there are a lot of other practice sites and I was looking for a general answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this generally depends on the tool. There are some practice targets that can be deployed and attacked locally and there are some that are hosted in the cloud. By and large, these tools aren’t exactly giving a sterile environment (especially the cloud-based ones). This is actually a good thing, as targets in the wild aren’t sterile either. A lot of systems and applications can be assumed to be attacked by multiple agents at once all time anyway, so practicing with that sort of environment is all part of the training.